# Spring Batch Item Writer Run infinte times and can't end the writer process

Tags: spring-batch

QUESTION is: In reader class, i read data from database and writer class just print the list but it run so much times.
it cannot complete the process.
I attached the reader processor writer and xml class.
Any one suggested me for spring batch advice I cant understand the concept of reader and writer.

what things I missed here can any one advice me for this job

This is my xml file:

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:batch = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd"> 

    <import resource="context-model.xml"/> 
    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"   class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

 <!--THis is my reader writer and processor xml  -->
    <bean id="Reader" class="com.ibm.dao.Reader"/>
     <bean id="Processor" class="com.ibm.dao.Processor" />
    <!-- com.ibm.dao.Writer -->
     <bean id="Writer_pro" class=" com.ibm.dao.Writer">
     <!--   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> -->  
          </bean>

    <!-- Defining a job--> 
   <batch:job id = "CancellationLetterJob">  
      <!-- Defining a Step --> 
      <batch:step id = "step1"> 
<batch:tasklet> 
                <batch:chunk  reader="Reader" processor="Processor"  writer="Writer_pro" commit-interval='0' /> 
</batch:tasklet> 

      </batch:step>    
   </batch:job>  

</beans> 


****************and this is my writer class code********************:
```

public class Writer implements ItemWriter
    {

```
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TPOL> pol) throws Exception {

    System.out.println( pol.get(0).getId());

        for(TPOL list :pol )
        {
        System.out.println("list");

        }

        return;

    }
```

******* MY READER CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.batch.api.chunk.ItemProcessor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.itextpdf.text.log.SysoCounter;
import com.javatpoint.mypackage.TPOL;
import com.javatpoint.mypackage.test;
import com.javatpoint.mypackage.writer;
import com.ibm.dao.*;


public class Reader implements ItemReader<TPOL> {
    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);
    /*public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1) throws Exception {  


    }
    */
    @Override
    public TPOL read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        TPOL pol= new TPOL();
        //pol.setId(102);
        logger.info("TPOL data fetched");
        pol.setSystemid(1001);
        logger.info(pol);
        System.out.println("data updated in DB");
        return pol;
    }
```

***********MY PROCESSOR CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;

import com.javatpoint.mypackage.TPOL;
import com.javatpoint.mypackage.test;
import com.javatpoint.mypackage.writer;

public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<TPOL, TPOL>
{
    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);

    @Override
    public TPOL process(TPOL pol) throws Exception {


        Configuration  config= new AnnotationConfiguration().addAnnotatedClass(TPOL.class).configure();
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session sf=factory.openSession();   
        Transaction tr=sf.beginTransaction();

        logger.info(tr);

        sf.save(pol);
        logger.info("save"+sf.save(pol));

        Criteria cr = sf.createCriteria(TPOL.class);
        //cr.add(Restrictions.eq("systemid", 1000));
        ArrayList<TPOL> list = (ArrayList<TPOL>) cr.list();

        for(TPOL pol1: list)
        {
            //System.out.println("OUTPUT VALUE::"+pol1.getId()+" "+pol1.getSystemid());
            System.out.println(pol1.getSystemid());

    }
        //System.out.println("size"+list.size());
        //System.out.println("successfully saved "); 
        tr.commit();
        sf.close();
        return pol;
    }

}



MY output is :

log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
data updated in DB
Hibernate: insert into T_S2M_MAPPING (SYS_ID) values (?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID0_0_, this_.SYS_ID as SYS2_0_0_ from T_S2M_MAPPING this_
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
765
list
data updated in DB
Hibernate: insert into T_S2M_MAPPING (SYS_ID) values (?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID2_0_, this_.SYS_ID as SYS2_2_0_ from T_S2M_MAPPING this_
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
766
list
data updated in DB
Hibernate: insert into T_S2M_MAPPING (SYS_ID) values (?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID4_0_, this_.SYS_ID as SYS2_4_0_ from T_S2M_MAPPING this_
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
767
list
data updated
```

It cannot end the process. 
can any one advice me for this job

Answer (score 2):

The contract of an item reader is to return null when the data source is exhausted: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemReader

Your item reader never returns null, so the job will never end.

From the javadoc of the `ItemReader#read` method, implementations **must** return null at the end of the input data set: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html

Comment: Thanks  Ben, but in my reader part, that is the next input of writer. I need to return the reader value in to writer. Can u please help me to out of this.